# How to translate calculated Effect size into original units of measurement?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, effect-size, cohens-d

I am running a hypothesis test, and I am trying to share the statistics on this test to business user. I have calculated effect size using Cohen's d. Now I want to find a way to convert this effect size back into original units of measurement, something more consumable for the business user.
Means of the two groups are defect rates.

Comment: It depends on which version of Cohen's *d* you are using.  *All* versions are the difference in means divided by a standard deviation or estimate thereof, but there are several different forms for those SDs.  Please, then, provide details and explain why you might not have access to the SD you used to compute Cohen's *d*!